# Kafka - different configuration settings

Tags: apache-kafka

I am going through the documentation, and there seems to be there are lot of moving with respect to message processing like exactly once processing , at least once processing . And, the settings scattered here and there. There doesnt seem a single place that documents the properties need to be configured *rougly* for exactly once processing and atleast once processing.

I know there are many moving parts involved and *it always depends* . However, like i was mentioning before , what are the settings to be configured *atleast* to provide *exactly once processing* and *at most once* and *atleast once* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the first part of [Kafka FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIgetexactly-oncemessagingfromKafka?) that describes some approaches on how to avoid duplication on data production (i.e. on producer side):

> Exactly once semantics has two parts: avoiding duplication during data
>   production and avoiding duplicates during data consumption.
>
> **There are two approaches to getting exactly once semantics during data
>   production:**
>
> 1. Use a single-writer per partition and every time you get a network
>      error check the last message in that partition to see if your last
>      write succeeded
> 2. Include a primary key (UUID or something) in the
>      message and deduplicate on the consumer.
>
> If you do one of these things, the log that Kafka hosts will be
>   duplicate-free. However, reading without duplicates depends on some
>   co-operation from the consumer too. If the consumer is periodically
>   checkpointing its position then if it fails and restarts it will
>   restart from the checkpointed position. Thus if the data output and
>   the checkpoint are not written atomically it will be possible to get
>   duplicates here as well. This problem is particular to your storage
>   system. For example, if you are using a database you could commit
>   these together in a transaction. The HDFS loader Camus that LinkedIn
>   wrote does something like this for Hadoop loads. The other alternative
>   that doesn't require a transaction is to store the offset with the
>   data loaded and deduplicate using the topic/partition/offset
>   combination.